# Mongo shell db.model.find() not showing all the documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've defined my schema as follow but when I did `db.Titles.find()` from mongo shell I didn't get all the documents I have listed. What's wrong did I do ? The author is not showing in the mongo shell. I've tried to add some random document in the list still not showing in the mongo ? Once a model is created, can't it be updated or change? This created a problem when I try to access the list in template. Thanks, in advance.

**model :**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var tSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    sypnosis: String,
    category: Array,
    author: {
        username: String,
        id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
    },
    parts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Part"
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});

var Title = mongoose.model("Title", tSchema);
module.exports = Title;
```

**Mongo shell query :**

```
db.titles.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e0d140e7bf04c6a60f97dbd"),
        "category" : [ ],
        "parts" : [ ],
        "comments" : [ ],
        "title" : "New Title",
        "sypnosis" : "This si a sypnosis",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove all filters except "_id"?

Comment: What filters? I did not apply any filter, I think.